# ASP.NET Core MVC user registered from Employees Controller cannot log in as created user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an `EmployeeController`. I want to create employees in my application and when I create employees, I want employees to be able to log in as well as users of the application.

So in `EmployeesController`, I added these lines of code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,EmployeeRole,Department,Name,Phone,Address,Email,JoinedDate,Salary")] Employee employee)
{            
    var defaultUser = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = employee.Name,
            Email = employee.Email, 
            PhoneNumber = employee.Phone,
            Address = employee.Address,
            EmployeeRole = employee.EmployeeRole,
            Department = employee.Department,
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            PhoneNumberConfirmed = true
        };

    if (_userManager.Users.All(u =>u.Email != defaultUser.Email))
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(defaultUser.Email);

        if (user == null)
        {
            await _userManager.CreateAsync(defaultUser, "123Pa$$word.");
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(employee);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(employee);
}
```

When I create it created the user as well in the database. When I login with created user, I cannot login and showing Invalid Login Attempt.

But when I used the register method to create an account. I can log in.

[image]

Below is my `program.cs` DI for `IdentityUser`:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalDatabase");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()           
           .AddDefaultUI()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I have changed my `ApplicationDBContext` as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<HRMS.Models.Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HRMS.Models.Service> Services { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("Identity");

        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(name: "User");
        });

        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(name: "Role");
        });

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserRoles");
        });

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserClaims");
        });

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserLogins");
        });

        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("RoleClaims");
        });

        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("UserTokens");
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the registration.cs file.

```
      public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = CreateUser();

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }
```

Comment: 1: What is the registration method does and do you have the code for that? 2: Identity user may have a 'LockOut' flag or a flag to indicate if the user has been activated, what is the value of it?

Comment: LockoutEnd = null and LockoutEnables = True. I add registration code in question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is wrong with the question. But I can log in with user created from `EmployeeController` after changing exactly as in `Registration.cshtml.cs` provided default by `ASP.NET Core MVC`. Thanks for the adivce commented by @Bemn.

Below is the code I have added.

```
 public class EmployeesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<ApplicationUser> _userStore;
        private readonly IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser> _emailStore;
        

        public EmployeesController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore, IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
        }
        private IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser> GetEmailStore()
        {
            if (!_userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("The default UI requires a user store with email support.");
            }
            return (IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>)_userStore;
        }
        private ApplicationUser CreateUser()
        {
            try
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance<ApplicationUser>();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(ApplicationUser)}'. " +
                    $"Ensure that '{nameof(ApplicationUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively " +
                    $"override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,EmployeeRole,Department,Name,Phone,Address,Email,JoinedDate,Salary")] Employee employee)
        {            
            

            
            if (_userManager.Users.All(u =>u.Email != employee.Email))
            {
                var user = CreateUser();

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, employee.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, employee.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "User#12345");
                
                
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(employee);
```